# Snap application Heroku dropping privs did not work

Tags: permissions, sudo, snap, heroku

When executing the command `heroku` after installing via snap, it throws the error `dropping privs did not work`:

```
cesar@pc:~$ heroku --version
dropping privs did not work
```

But if I execute `sudo heroku` the command runs:

```
cesar@pc:~$ sudo heroku --version
 ▸    heroku-cli: update available from 6.16.4 to 6.99.0-ec9edad
heroku-cli/6.16.4 (linux-x86) node-v9.9.0
```

Additional Information:

```
cesar@pc:~$ snap version
snap    2.36.1
snapd   2.36.1
series  16
ubuntu  16.04
kernel  4.4.0-139-generic`

cesar@pc:~$ snap list
Name    Version                     Rev   Tracking  Publisher   Notes
core    16-2.36.1                   5900  stable    canonical✓  core
heroku  v6.16.4+git2.3916a9e-dirty  1613  stable    heroku✓     classic
```

`Linux version 4.4.0-139-generic (buildd@lgw01-amd64-031) (gcc version 5.4.0 20160609 (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.10) ) #165-Ubuntu SMP Wed Oct 24 10:55:26 UTC 2018`

Comment: Have you modified your user somehow? what is the output of `id`?

Comment: I have not modified my user. I do not know how to get the `id` you mention.

Comment: `id` is just a command. You just need to run it in a terminal and it should output info about your user and its groups.

Comment: I understand, thank you. When executing 'id' `uid=1000(cesar) gid=0(root) grupos=0(root),4(adm),20(dialout),21(fax),24(cdrom),25(floppy),26(tape),27(sudo),30(dip),44(video),46(plugdev),120(lpadmin),121(sambashare)`